# grep on remote host with multiple commands

Tags: bash, grep, sshd, hp-ux

**2nd Command is getting ignored**

```
ssh -q -t -o ConnectTimeout=10 learnserver sudo su - root -c 'hostname' && "/grep PermitRootLogin /opt/ssh/etc/sshd_config/"
```

Comment: As a suggestion. try to do that by passing a script to ssh. Something like create a script that if you run locally on that remote machine would do what you wanted and do `ssh remote-machine < yourScript.sh`

Comment: One of your edits added a shell script with an `ssh` command that's significantly different from the ssh command that's in your question now. Make sure that the ssh command in your question is an accurate representation of the command that you're actually running.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the command set as a script to the ssh. For your case for example

```bsh
{
  echo "sudo su -"
  echo "hostname"
  echo "grep PermitRootLogin /opt/ssh/etc/sshd_config/"
} > /tmp/some-script.sh
```

and then

`ssh your-remote < /tmp/some-script.sh`

note the "script creation" is just an example for how your script should be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you really don't need `sudo su` and you certainly don't need `sudo su - root`. The `su` command defaults to root, but the `sudo` command exists to run commands that need to be run as root. So you simply need `sudo command`. That said, you should avoid running commands as root unless it is actually needed, and `hostname` does not require root. With all this in mind, this should do what you need:

```
ssh -q -t -o ConnectTimeout=10 learnserver sh -c "hostname && sudo grep PermitRootLogin /opt/ssh/etc/sshd_config"
```

In other words, instead of trying to run multiple commands, make your many commands into one. Here, we are using `sh -c command` which means "start `sh` and then run `command`".